# De Branges's theorem and perspective on Sheaf theory

Tags: mathematics-social-history, algebraic-geometry

As far as I know, there is an intuitive and easy way to think about sheaf theory through the Taylor series.
For example, in the case of stalk, which is one of the important concepts in sheaf, we can think of the Taylor series around point $p$.  But I became curious about the background that led me to think this way.

And I know that De Branges's theorem, which proved Bieberbach's conjecture [(see this wikipedia article!)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem), is related to this content. Was it from the moment De Branges's theorem appeared that we began to view sheaf theory from the perspective of Taylor series?

I read the [following pdf file](http://kobra.bibliothek.uni-kassel.de/bitstream/urn:nbn:de:hebis:34-200604038936/1/prep0513.pdf) attached to the wikipedia article, but it did not provide a specific answer.  If anyone knows anything about this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Bieberbach's conjecture played no role historically in viewing holomorphic germs (Taylor series) in terms of sheaves. Leray's original 1946 definition of a sheaf (*faisceaux* in French) parallels that of a germ, which goes back to Weierstrass. "*Cartan presumably made the connection between Leray's definition and the notion of germs... in the first of his papers on the connection between faisceaux and complex analysis, Cartan 1950*", [Gray, Fragments of the history of sheaf theory](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0061812). All of this much predates de Branges's 1985 proof.

Comment: @Conifold I was wrong about the Bieberbach conjecture.  Thank you for your comment.